# How to filter data using RxJS observables based on a pattern

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5

I am using RxJS observables in my Angular 2 application.I am trying to get a list of employee and if the employee id ends with 'MA' i dont want them to be added to the list. Following is my code:

```
    getEmployees(): any {
    return this.employeeService.get("http://localhost:9080/employees")
                .map((employees: any) => employees.map((employee: any) => {
                    let empcode: string = employee.empcode;
                    if (empcode.lastIndexOf("MA") == -1) {
                        return { empText: empcode+ ' - ' + employee.empName, data: employee};
                    }
                        return { empText: '', data : null};
                }));
}
```

I am not able to filter the records and it is returning me all the values.I have two return statements so it is returning all the value but if I remove one of them I get the following error:

no best common type exists among return expressions

The json returned by the web service is in the following format:

```
{
employeeCode: "EMPCT", 
employeeName: "Tom", 
role: "HR"
}
```

So could you let me know what is the best way to filter records returned by the web service in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the `filter` function?

```
getEmployees(): any {
  return this.employeeService.get("http://localhost:9080/employees")
              .map((employees: any) => items.filter((employee: any) => {
                  let empcode: string = employee.empcode;
                  return ((ifscode.lastIndexOf("MA") == -1); 
              }));
}
```

not sure where the ifscode comes from. Anyways, you should use filter. If you need further transformation, you can chain a `.map()` operation.

Comment: "Why not use the filter function?" Yes, of course he should. But not the `filter` from `Array`. He should rather use the filter from `Observable`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40678593/2398593

Comment: In general I agree with you only that here the sequence is comprised of arrays. RX filter will pass or block the entire result and this is not the desired behavior in this case

Comment: @Meir I was able to get the filtered records. But I want to return employeename+Employeecode to the component.Any idea how I could do that.

Comment: Do your original mapping (without the condition testing) after the filter: items.filter(...).map(...)

Answer (score 1):

```
getEmployees(): any {
    return this.employeeService.get("http://localhost:9080/employees")
                .map((employees: any) => {
                    let filtered = employees.json().filter((employee) => {
                      let empcode: string = employee.empcode;
                      if (ifscode.lastIndexOf("MA") == -1) {
                        return true;
                      } else {
                        return false;
                      }
                    });
                  return filtered;
                }));
}
```

Comment: I want to return the empcode and employee name instead of true and false and incase the employee code ends with MA then I dont want to return that employee.Could you let me know how I can do that using the solution that you suggested.

Comment: With it you will get all the details of employee which is returned from API. check it once and if possible update your question with response you get from API.

Comment: I have updated the sample json returned by the API. It returns me records in that format. In the question I have mentioned the format in which I want the data to be returned so how can I do that with the solution mentioned above.

Comment: have you checked result by doing `console.log` in your component where you are calling `getEmployees` function ?

Comment: I checked the result in the network tab of chrome and it still returns the employees with the code ending with MA.

Comment: need not required to check in network tab of chrome. if `getEmployees ` function is in `component`  then you have to add `.subscribe((res) => { return res;})` after map.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128460/discussion-between-valla-and-ranakrunal9).